# Array property returns calculation of 2 other arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

Is it possible to have an array property that returns a calculation of 2 other arrays at the same index?

```
public ushort[] LowLimit{ get; set; }

public ushort[] Range{ get; set; }

public ushort[] HiLimit {
    get {
     return LowLimit + Range;
    }
}
```

So if I called `HiLimit[0]` it would return `LowLimit[0] + Range[0]`. This is not working but there must be a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) operator:

> Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two
>   sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

```
public ushort[] HiLimit => LowLimit.Zip(Range, (l,r) => (ushort)(l + r)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Wont you need a cast? `(ushort)(l + r)`

Comment: I am getting an error, because it is returning an int[] instead of a ushort[]

Comment: yup... LowLimit.Zip(Range, (l, r) => (ushort)(l + r)).ToArray();

Comment: @AlexK. yep, you are totally right. forgot about those integers everywhere :)

Comment: Thank you both for the assistance. Much appreciated

Comment: What about an associated setter? ie setting the HiLimit would perform a calculation with LowLimit and set the Range.

Comment: @jsun5192 that's definitely another question :)